# Read EventArgs from Richtextbox-Scroll event via Powershell

Tags: powershell, events, richtextbox, eventargs

```
$DebugPreference = "Continue"
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.size  = "400,400"
$rtb = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$rtb.size  = "350,350"
$rtb.text = 1..1000
$form.controls.add($rtb)

$rtb.add_VScroll({ 
    param($sender, $eventargs) 
    Write-Debug "Scroll Event $(get-date -format `"mm:ss:ms`")`r`n $($eventargs | out-string) "
})

$form.showdialog()
```

I am trying to read the eventargs from the VScroll -Event, specifically the [ScrollEventArgs.Type-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx). I tried it as I usually do (see example code), but for some reason $eventargs just contains a string "system.eventargs". What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an *explanation*, but not a *solution*:

Type [`[System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs) applies to the `Scroll` event of *different* controls:

> The `Scroll` event occurs for the `DataGridView`, `ScrollableControl`, `ScrollBar`, and `DataGrid` controls.

By contrast, a rich text-box's [`VScroll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.vscroll) event delegate receives the [`[System.EventArgs]::Empty` singleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventargs.empty), signifying that the event *provides no data* (`[System.EventArgs]::Empty` has no properties and therefore stringifies to simply its *type name*).